# C#: Read an image from the database using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, image, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have been trying to read a image file using a stored procedure. The below given is that stored procedure to get the image file.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE readImage 
    @sID int,
    @img image output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @img=(SELECT s_Image FROM Student WHERE s_ID=@sID);
END
GO
```

Below given is the code to get the value returned from the stored procedure.

```
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    Connect conn = new Connect();
    con = conn.getConnected();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("readImage", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@sID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 17;
    SqlParameter retValue = cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image);
    retValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])retValue.Value);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
    }
```

However when I try to run the code I get a `SqlException`:

> *Procedure or function 'readImage' expects parameter '@img', which was not supplied.*

Even though I have already passed the `@img` variable. Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

change  `retValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;` to 
 `retValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: After changing the above statement I got an error as "Byte[][1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0"

Comment: @user1122359:VarChar and NVarChar are variable width character fields (thus var+char). You have to set the length, otherwise the default is zero.

Comment: @user1122359:check where u r forgotten to set size of varchar or nvarchar

Comment: @user1122359:if u have set all then try it retValue.DbType = DbType.image;

Comment: there's no DbType.Image but has all other types. Should it be SByte?

Comment: Also there's no varchar or nvarchar set but its image